# ExtJS4: Model with hasMany loads only first nested attribute

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I try to load a JSON reply from my server which has nested attributes via the model's load function. But somehow, only the first entry of my nested attributes set gets parsed.

I'm trying to load a JSON file like the following:

```
{
   "id" : "2",
   "name" : "John",
   "logins" : [
      {
         "id" : "4",
         "person_id" : "2",
         "date" : "2012-01-18 01:00:06"
      },{
         "id" : "9",
         "person_id" : "2",
         "date" : "2012-01-18 19:36:13"
      },{
         "id" : "12",
         "person_id" : "2",
         "date" : "2012-01-19 00:12:32"
      }]
}
```

and I have two models like the following:

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.model.Person', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
        idProperty : 'id',
        fields : [{
                    name : 'id',
                    type : 'int'
                }, {
                    name : 'name',
                    type : 'string'
                }],
        hasMany : [{
                model: 'MyAppName.model.Login',
                name: 'logins',
                associationKey: 'logins'
        }],
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : '../index.php?format=json',
            reader : {
                type : 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.model.Login', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
        fields : [{
                    name : 'id',
                    type : 'int'
                }, {
                    name : 'person_id',
                    type : 'int'
                }, {
                    name : 'date',
                    type : 'date'
                }],
        belongsTo: [{
            model: 'MyAppName.model.Person', 
            associationKey: 'logins'
        }]  
    }
});
```

and I try to load a new person with its data via

```
MyAppName.model.Person.load(personId, {scope: ..., ..., success: function(record, operation) { -someFancyCode-} })
```

But the record I retrieve in the success function now only contains one login dataset. Have I done something wrong?

Thanks!
Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, Model doesn't load nested data by itself, not very well at least, it has some know problems with that, so, the better choice is to create a store and load your models via that store, something among these lines:

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }],
    hasMany: [{
        model: 'MyAppName.model.Login',
        name: 'logins'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyAppName.model.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'person_id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'date',
        type: 'date'
    }],
    belongsTo: [{
        model: 'MyAppName.model.Person'
    }]
});
var data = {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "logins": [{
        "id": "4",
        "person_id": "2",
        "date": "2012-01-18 01:00:06"
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "person_id": "2",
        "date": "2012-01-18 19:36:13"
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "person_id": "2",
        "date": "2012-01-19 00:12:32"
    }]
};
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'MyAppName.model.Person',
    data: data
});
var instanceModel = store.getAt(0);
//Show 'Person' model contents.
console.info(instanceModel);

//Show 'logins' for that person
console.info(instanceModel.logins());
```

Check the corresponding [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/voidmain/ktWpQ/)

Hope this gets you on the right track.